# Unable to install R packages from source on a fresh R installation

Tags: r, rcpp, rstan, rtools

I am trying to install rstan but am coming up with immense difficulty trying to install packages from source. I am currently running R version 4.3.0 (windows 11, 64 bit) and have installed rtools43.

To illustrate the problem, if I try and run this command:

`install.packages("Rcpp", type="source")`

I get this output:

`Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status`

I am completely stuck on this. I have tried reinstalling R, RStudio and rtools multiple times and I also tried installing an earlier version of R and rtools42. This also did not fix the problem. ChatGPT was also not much help here either.

If someone could help me troubleshoot this, I would be extremely grateful as I really could do with getting rstan working.

Comment: Install rtools43 instead of rtools42, and try without the argument `type = "source"`.

Comment: Was there no other error at all before that? That was the only output you received? Normally there's more descriptive output that tells you what exactly went wrong. Maybe run `pkgbuild::has_rtools(debug=TRUE)` if you can install `pkgbuild` to make sure Rtools is installed properly.

Comment: Why source?  You can install 'pre-made, ready-to-use, binary` packages for both `Rcpp` and `rstan` from CRAN which, even if they come as binaries, should allow you to run stan models involving compilation.   As for 'source install is failing me': Not an `Rcpp`.  The package install _if your setup is correct_ and how to get there on Windows (or other specific OS instances) is described in many places.

Comment: You do not even need `pkgbuild`.  Install `Rcpp` has a binary from CRAN.  Then run `Rcpp::evalCpp("21 + 21")` and the official answer to all things should appear. If not, you have R / Rtools / ... issues you need to address locally.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I need to install from source because the binary package has a known issue (explained here - https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started). I currently have rtools43 installed and R version 4.3.0.

Comment: The output from```pkgbuild::has_rtools(debug=TRUE)``` is weird. I get this:

```WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 4.3.0 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found: 4.3.5550)```


```Please download and install Rtools 4.2 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ or https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/winutf8/ucrt3/.```

Comment: Sorry, I missed @MrFlick's question. No, there are no other errors. The output from attempting to install the Rcpp package from source is literally just:

```trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2936173 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB```

```Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status```

```The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk1UnY6\downloaded_packages’```

Comment: Sorry to bump this thread, but I am still having difficulties with this. If anybody does have any ideas or could help me troubleshoot this, I would be really grateful.